# Active Record WHERE Query not getting a field

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I am trying a "Keyword" search. I am looking in the fields ARTWORK_title and ARTWORK_keywords. The ARTWORK_keywords field is where the user can enter multiple tags to search on.

I have built a query up and feel this is the right way, But I am just not getting ARTWORK_title passed back through in the DB Query.

My PHP Function is as follows....

```
$my_keywords = explode(",", $search_string);

    $searchfields = array('ARTWORK_title', 'ARTWORK_keywords');

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('artwork');
    $this->db->where('ARTWORK_status', '1');

    //$where_string = '(';

    foreach($my_keywords as $keyword)
    {
        foreach($searchfields as $field)
        {
            $where_string = $field . ' LIKE \'%' . $keyword . '%\' ';
        }


        //$where_string .= substr($where_string, 4) . ')';

        $this->db->where($where_string);
}
```

However when profiling the SQL Query I am getting the following MySQL Query back....

> SELECT *
>   FROM (`artwork`)
>   WHERE `ARTWORK_status` = '1'
>   AND `ARTWORK_keywords` LIKE '%Blue%' 
>   AND `ARTWORK_keywords` LIKE '%Orange%'

It is just not getting the ARTWORK_title field in the query at all.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are erasing the `$where_string` value with each iteration.

Modify it like this:

```
$where_string = '';    
$counter = 0;
foreach($my_keywords as $keyword)
{
    foreach($searchfields as $field)
    {
        if ($counter > 0) {
           $where_string .= ' AND ';    
        }
        $where_string .= $field . ' LIKE \'%' . $keyword . '%\' ';
        $counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yan thats getting the field back. But the query is now giving me an MYSQL Error : 

SELECT * FROM (`artwork`) WHERE `ARTWORK_status` = '1' AND `ARTWORK_title` LIKE '%Blue%' ARTWORK_keywords LIKE '%Blue%' ARTWORK_title LIKE '%Orange%' ARTWORK_keywords LIKE '%Orange%' 

Is what its trying to run

Comment: New MySQL Error on that : Unknown column ' AND '

Comment: That seems fine thanks Yan. Problem I'm getting now is its not returning any results :(

Comment: You might want to change it to `OR` and `or_where`?

Comment: Hi Yan, My Database contains a table that has "ARTWORK_keywords" in it. These keywords are seperated like follows : "Blue,Orange". Running a $this->db->or_where($where_string); brings back "9" records, But some of those records do not contain neither Orange or Blue.

Comment: please paste here the actual query which returns 9 results.

Comment: Sure the query for that is : SELECT *
FROM (`artwork`)
WHERE `ARTWORK_status` = '1'
OR `ARTWORK_title` LIKE '%Blue%' AND ARTWORK_keywords LIKE '%Blue%' AND ARTWORK_title LIKE '%Orange%' AND ARTWORK_keywords LIKE '%Orange%' I suspect its something around the LIKES..?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13730/discussion-between-yan-and-stublackett)